# DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have following code to execute sql quesry in Oracle db:

```
try:
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(DB_LOGIN+"/"+DB_PWD+"@"+SID)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, ex:
    error, = ex.args
    print 'Error.code =', error.code
    print 'Error.message =' , error.message
    print 'Error.offset =', error.offset
    conn.rollback()
```

I got error: `DatabaseError: <cx_Orac...40066758>`.

Why I don't see full error message in console? Looks like exception part is not executed. 
I use python 2.5 and oracle 10.2.0 on linux.

Update: After some investigation I found out that the error is `DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character`.

My sql string is like: `sql = "SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE DESC  = '" + str(desc[0]) + "';"`. This is generated string: `"SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE DESC  = '3312';"`

When I execute the same request in SQL Developer it works. So what I do wrong?

Comment: Remove the trailing semi colon in your query string. The OCI just need your query.. No terminators needed!

Answer (score 36):

Delete the semicolon:

```
sql = "SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE DESC  = '" + str(desc[0]) + "'"
```

Comment: really helpful @Tedezed

Comment: Basic error, we test with semicolon in SQL editor, happens all the time.